# 7segment driver with PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, led-driver, 7segmentdisplay

I'm trying to drive a 7segment using PIC microcontroller.
This is the circuit diagram:

[image]

In the picture, PIC means some ports of the PIC microcontroller. I want to pass 3 mA through each LED, and since we have 8 LEDs in a 7segment that means 8*3 mA through each transistor that is supposed to drive the 7segment digits (in the circuit each transistor is driving one digit of the 7segment). According to the datasheet of transistor the minimum beta of the transistor is 40.
Here are my calculations:

[image]

So, is my calculation right?

- 7segment part number is TOF-3407
- Q1 is BC817
- PIC model is PIC18f46k80, and 7segment is connected to PORTB

Comment: Is that a ‘k’ symbol above the ‘7” in the Rb calculation?  When I divide 5.08V by 0.6mA I get 8467 ohms.  Even so, I don’t think the calculations are using the correct numbers.

Comment: yes, that's a "k" symbol. you are supposed to subtract 5 by 0.8 and then divide it by 0.5mA

Comment: Oh, that’s a ‘-‘ sign, I thought it was a decimal point.

Comment: Short answer: Calculations are OK. However, you should regard \$R_b=7k\$ as an upper limit. You want to ensure the transistor is *saturated*, so roughly doubling base current is a reasonable way to do this...\$R_b\$ might become 3300 ohms.

Comment: Are you sure that 3mA per LED is enough? Looks like you are multiplexing four digits. While 3mA might be enough if one digit was ON *all the time*, 3mA might not be enough when each digit is ON 25% (or a little less). Some 7-segment LEDs are more efficient than others.

Comment: @HandyHowie Yup.

Comment: @glen_geek Good point, thank you so much.
3mA is only for one LED of a digit. So, basically, since each digit has 8 LEDs, each transistor draws 24mA.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't power the LEDs directly from the PIC pins? Apparently they can source up to 20mA just fine. Ditch the BJT and place a suitable series resistor between the pin and each segment, ground on the other side, done. (Or have the MCU sink the current, works fine too but you get inverted logic.)

Comment: @glen_geek I think you have a point, the datasheet even recommends 12mA. I wonder if OP has actually driven a segment at 3mA at 25% duty cycle? I bet it would be pretty dim.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble following your calculations and you have not provided an actual part number for the seven-segment display.  They are not all the same.

You also said:

> According to the datasheet of transistor the minimum beta of the
> transistor is 40

That's pretty much irrelevant for a switching circuit.  You only need to ensure that the PIC signal to the base of the transistor puts it into saturation.

I've redrawn one of the 7 circuits below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRGyDx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is that you have not specified to us and of the parameters such as V1, R1, D1's forward voltage drop or Q1's Vce at saturation.  As such we can only to a generalized solution here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMESN3.png)</sup>

So the current is now simple enough to calculate:

Iled = (Vcc - Vforward - Vce)/R1

Comment: Hi let's say the 7segment part number is 3461bs. The datasheet says it has a forward voltage drop of 1.8 volts. 
You said:
"That's pretty much irrelevant for a switching circuit. You only need to ensure that the PIC signal to the base of the transistor puts it into saturation."
How can I do that?
V1 is the microcontroller output which is 5 volts. R1 has to be calculated. Q1 is BC817 with a saturation voltage of 0.7 volt.
Anything else you need?

Comment: What specific PIC model are you using and which outputs are connected to these transistors?

Comment: @MohsenRazzaghi Please add the relevant information to the question. This is a 4 digit multiplexed 7 segment LED. How are the anodes and cathodes connected?

Comment: @jwh20 
PIC model is PIC18f46k80, and 7segment is connected to PORTB

Comment: @devnull
The anodes and cathodes are connected as they are depicted in the picture I posted above.

Comment: @jwh20
So what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Can't a PIC sink about more than 3 mA per pin?

From the PIC16F877 data sheet  - the chip requires that there must be less than 200 mA sunk from a port and less sunk than 25 mA from any pin.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this answers the OP's question.  I'm not saying this data is not relevant, just that it's not directly an answer.

Comment: Could this be a XY problem?

Comment: That's always a possibility.

Comment: Yes, they can. But I don't need more than 3 mA.